# Text to speech using AWSPolly in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use the AWSPolly service from amazon to add speech synthesis to an application I am building. However I am having a problem because the when the code is executed, it throws a very long error that I dont know how to interpret. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AWSPolly
import AWSCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()

func btn_pressed() {
    let input = AWSPollySynthesizeSpeechURLBuilderRequest()

    input.text = "Hello, this is a text to speech demo."
    input.outputFormat = .mp3
    input.voiceId = .brian
    let builder = AWSPollySynthesizeSpeechURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(input)

    builder.continueOnSuccessWith { (awsTask: AWSTask<NSURL>) -> Any? in
        let url = awsTask.result!

        self.audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL))
        self.audioPlayer.play()

        return nil
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest2, identityPoolId: "####################")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest2, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 60, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.setTitle("Press me", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btn_pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    print("loaded.")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

And the error is:

```
2017-02-15 17:42:09.890798 test[430:62027] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:537 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request headers:
{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Host = "cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.5.0 iOS/10.2.1 en_CA";
    "X-Amz-Date" = 20170215T224209Z;
    "X-Amz-Target" = "AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId";
}
2017-02-15 17:42:09.891387 test[430:62027] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:555 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request body:
{"IdentityPoolId":"####################################"}
2017-02-15 17:42:10.846816 test[430:62029] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:566 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersForResponse:] | Response headers:
{
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 63;
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Date = "Wed, 15 Feb 2017 22:42:10 GMT";
    "x-amzn-RequestId" = "fcdefa89-f3cf-11e6-8f0c-c314b72b55aa";
}
2017-02-15 17:42:10.847373 test[430:62029] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"IdentityId":"#######################################"}
2017-02-15 17:42:10.891167 test[430:62029] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:537 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request headers:
{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Host = "cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.5.0 iOS/10.2.1 en_CA";
    "X-Amz-Date" = 20170215T224210Z;
    "X-Amz-Target" = "AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity";
}
2017-02-15 17:42:10.891564 test[430:62029] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:555 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersAndBodyForRequest:] | Request body:
{"IdentityId":"########################################"}
2017-02-15 17:42:11.695316 test[430:62030] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:566 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersForResponse:] | Response headers:
{
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 1612;
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Date = "Wed, 15 Feb 2017 22:42:11 GMT";
    "x-amzn-RequestId" = "fd589752-f3cf-11e6-a1d9-15c6fbfc10f1";
}
2017-02-15 17:42:11.700278 test[430:62030] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"Credentials":{"AccessKeyId":"################","Expiration":1.487202131E9,"SecretKey":"###################","SessionToken":"(Random letters, numbers and symbols)="},"IdentityId":"########################"}
```

I just hid all of the personal information

Edit:

here is the verbose output (i believe)

```
host
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855]
2017-02-17 21:31:49.761067 test[2068:529431] AWSiOSSDK v2.5.0 [Verbose] AWSSignature.m line:468 | __165+[AWSSignatureV4Signer generateQueryStringForSignatureV4WithCredentialProvider:httpMethod:expireDuration:endpoint:keyPath:requestHeaders:requestParameters:signBody:]_block_invoke | AWS4 PresignedURL String to Sign: [AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170218T023149Z
20170218/us-west-2/polly/aws4_request
8a91c47ca194ace68a95f59ccbac9d8813f9487c73b1a83b5861e821f0095db0]
```

Comment: What is the error? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: That's all it gives me. I am not really sure what the error is

Comment: What you provided looks like a bunch of requests and responses

Comment: After setting breakpoints in the code, this output ends up going away but still no audio @LisaMShon

Comment: Did you try using the Polly sample by AWS Mobile SDK?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work though... I don't know why @LisaMShon

Comment: Can you add `AWSLogger.default().logLevel = .verbose` and update the output?

Comment: I have just updated @donkon